# Aureliajs where is Promise.race([

Tags: aurelia

Why is Promise.race([... undefined in the current version of aurelia?

You can see a good example of its use at:  [Error handling for fetch() in Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520790/error-handling-for-fetch-in-aurelia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.race` is supported either by the browser, or by a polyfill you supply. Aurelia does not supply a Promise polyfill. You can use Bluebird (as the skeletons do), or you can use the built-in Promises if you don't need to support older browsers. Current browser support for `Promise.race` can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

Comment: Hmmm I use Firefox 48.0.1 and Safari 9.1.2  which are supposed to support Promise.race but I still get the error:  
Inner Error:
Message: Promise.race is not a function

I will look into Bluebird.

Answer (score 3):

In my aurelia-app build with aurelia-cli only Bluebird core was bundled, but Promise.race is only included in the full version.

In aurelia.json in the section "prepend", change "bluebird.core.js" to "bluebird.min.js"

```
"prepend": [
      "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js",
      ...
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with Asheley's comment I was able to figure it out.  I used bluebird as he suggested:

```
aurelia.json
     ...{
        "name": "bluebird",
        "path": "../node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min"
      },...
```

Inside the class:

```
...
import {Promise} from 'bluebird';
...
   Promise.race([ // is now available
...
```